# Change Function return NaN Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure in my page:

**Fieldset:**

*Size*

*Options*

That shows Was, Now and You Save Price

Then I have JQuery in place that convert the above into float and shows the Save Price in percentage. It all works as intended until I change for instance the Size  and the Options. To overcome this I've tried to use `.change(function()`. However when I change the value from the selected menu and it returns **NaN**.
Can you please help?

Here is my JS Code:

```js
$(".product-options").change(function() {


      var oldPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('.old-price-item .price .price').text().replace('£', ''), 10);
      var savePrice = parseFloat(jQuery('.special-price .price .price').text().replace('£', ''), 10);
      var youSave = savePrice / (oldPrice / 100);
      var n = parseFloat(youSave).toFixed(2);

      $('div.ratio-div').html('<p>' + n + ' % OFF</p>');

      $('div.save-price-div').html('<p>£' + savePrice + ' OFF</p>');


    }).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options-container-big">
  <fieldset class="product-options" id="product-options-wrapper">
    <dl class="attribute-list">
      <dt id="attribute122_row" style="position: relative;"><label class=
            "required product-options__label" for=
            "attribute122">Size</label></dt>
      <dd>
        <div class="input-select input-select--alternate">
          <select class="validate-select super-attribute-select validation-passed" data-attribute="item-size" data-choosetxt="Size" data-role="none" id="attribute122" name="super_attribute[122]">
            <option value="">
              Size
            </option>
            <option value="235">
              Single
            </option>
            <option value="238">
              Double
            </option>
            <option value="239">
              King
            </option>
          </select>
        </div><span class="item-size-warning" id="attribute122-warning" style="display:none;"></span>
      </dd>
      <dt id="attribute129_row" style="position: relative;"><label class=
            "required product-options__label" for=
            "attribute129">Storage</label></dt>
      <dd class="last">
        <div class="input-select input-select--alternate">
          <select class="validate-select super-attribute-select" data-attribute="storage" data-choosetxt="Storage" data-role="none" id="attribute129" name="super_attribute[129]">
            <option value="">
              Storage
            </option>
            <option value="310">
              No Drawers
            </option>
            <option value="312">
              2 Drawers
            </option>
            <option value="313">
              4 Drawers
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="product-options-bottom">
    <div class="add-to-cart">
      <div class="price-box">
        <div class="old-price">
          <ul id="old-price-15511">
            <li class="old-price-item">
              <div class="line-through">
                &nbsp;
              </div><span class="price-label">Was</span>
              <span class="price"><span class=
                            "currency">£</span></span>
            </li>
            <li class="old-price-item">
              <div class="line-through">
                &nbsp;
              </div><span class="price-label">Was</span>
              <span class="price"><span class=
                            "currency">£</span></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <p class="special-price"><span class="price-label">You
                Save</span>  <span class="currency-special-price">£</span>
          <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-15511"></span>
        </p><span class="regular-price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"></span>
        <meta content="GBP">
      </div>
      <div class="product-stock-status">
        <div class="product-stock-status__wrapper">
          <span class="title">In Stock</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Please note** The fieldset provide different price for Size only or Size + different option.

Comment: Can you create a code snippet please including your html too?

Comment: @Alex it is quite complicated extracting only that bit from the page. Can you see something that is not as it should be in the JS code?

Comment: I want your html if is possible(at least the elements affect `change`).

Comment: `parseFloat("")` is _NaN_

Comment: @Alex I've updated my question

Comment: @Grundy it is working with the default values. The issue appears when selecting different size

Comment: `jQuery('.old-price-item .price .price').length == 0` so you have not this element in your html

Comment: Basically the price is dynamically generated. Narrowing down the issue it seems that when reload it does not pick up was price and save price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the HTML provided, it looks like you have incorrectly doubled up the class selector called "`price`" in the jQuery selectors.

Try these instead:

```
var oldPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('.old-price-item .price .currency').last().text().replace('£', ''), 10);
var savePrice = parseFloat(jQuery('.special-price .price').text().replace('£', ''), 10);
```

It is difficult to know for certain because the html is missing the numbers. I guess you either edited the price out, or it is generated dynamically by some other script not shown.

Here is a cut down version of the html to illustrate what your selectors are choosing:

http://jsbin.com/heduju/5/edit?html,js,console,output

**Update**

Just noticed that there are multiple matches to the first selector so I added `.last()` to the selector as well (assuming that the last was price is used for the calculation).

http://jsbin.com/jegeqe/17/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: It seems that it is working when initially load and then it can not convert the string into number and return NaN

Comment: The reason why it was not working was because I was targeting .special-price .price .price rather than .special-price .price

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery('.old-price-item .price .price').text()` returns `""` (empty string), so `parseFloat()` is `NaN`.

Comment: do you know how to overcome that?